# What is the correct way to use Linq to reference the table you instantiate with your ViewModel as a list to generate a list of 'SelectListItems'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to generate a strongly typed list of Roles in my controller along with two other lists which will be used in my view as various filters for sending an email.  I'm aware I can generate the Roles list using the following:

```
var viewModel = new ListViewModel
        {
            Roles = db.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Id.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList(),
        };
```

However as I am also wanting to pass two other lists to my controller I would prefer to attain the list of roles by writing the query in the following way:

```
var viewModel = db.Roles

           .Select(x => new SendGroupEmailViewModel
           {
               Roles = x.Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Id.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList(),

           };
```

That way I can then attain my other two lists as part of the same query, as opposed to the previous method where they would have to be effectively separate queries to the db.  Obviously what is above doesn't work, I am unable .Select on the role table by writing Roles = x.Select.

My question is, why am I unable to do this and what is the correct way to query the Roles table when writing it in a similar way to the above?

Just to be clear, the reason it has to be var viewModel = db.Roles is because for whatever reason I can't access the ID/Name Roles list otherwise due to how Identity is setup in MVC.  I know there are other ways of attaining the list, I would just like to know how it can be done this specific way?

edit - I should add that Roles in my viewModel is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
```

Comment: you need to use (in viewbag or viewmodel )  SelectList sList = new SelectList(selectList, "Text", "Value", selected);

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not sure how that answers my question or helps me at all, could you explain what you mean?  How does that fit into the specific style of query I wrote in the second example and how does it help me reference the Roles table in the manner I require within that query?

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
var oList = db.Roles.Select(x => new SendGroupEmailViewModel
               {
                   Roles = x.Roles.Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Id.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();

    ViewData.myList = new SelectList(oList,

               }, 
                    "Value", "Text", 15); // 15 = selected item or you can omit this value
```

View

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("myList") %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but that doesn't work.  My issue is that I can't directly ".Select" on the roles table using that style of query.  So x.Roles.Select or x.Select both do not work.  I can already generate the appropriate list so the ViewData part of your answer is not required.

Comment: what error/result do you get?  can you try "var oList = from oRole in db.Roles select oRole"

Comment: The error is that .Select does not exist in the context.  I can't x.Select using the type of query I listed.  Thanks for the other suggestion but as I tried to explain in my question, I can already get the list exactly how I want it using the first query, my question is purely about referencing the roles table using the specific style of the second query and what you have suggested there is written differently to the second query.  In short, my problem isn't achieving the result, it is achieving the result using the specific format used in the second example of my question.